# jquery click event for buttons having same id

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclicklistener

I am having a table structure like this

```
<table>
  <c forEach var="item" items="${manyItems}">
    <tr>
       <td id="item1"> ${item.data1} </td>
       <td id="item2"> ${item.data2} </td>
       <td> <button id="deleteButton"/> </td>
    </tr>
  </c:forEach>
</table>
```

> Now I want to add a **click event** to the **deleteButton**

In my jquery is like this:

```
$(function() {
  $('#deleteButton').click(function() {
    var ele = $(this).parent();
    /* fetch the other <td> siblings of the #deleteButton */
    /* delete code goes here having an ajax query*/
  });
});
```

This code is only deleting the 1st row of the table, but does not work on any other row.

I believe this is because we need to have distinct id's?

Kindly guide me to a good solution.

Comment: cannot have same id on elements

Comment: You failed at ***"having same id"***, there's no such thing, it's invalid, and you seem to already know it, so why the misnomer title ?

Comment: `id` selector returns the first matched element, while `class` selector returns the collection of matched elements

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are creating duplicate IDs, **Identifiers in HTML must be unique** and this is the expected behavior.

*Use class*, Here In example below I have converted `deleteButton` in to a CSS class so that we can use [Class Selector (".class")](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)

```
<button class="deleteButton"/>
```

*Script*

```
  $('.deleteButton').click(function() {
    var ele = $(this).parent();

  });
```

Answer (score 2):

Issue is the same ids for multiple elements in a single page. When this happens browser only looks for first instance of it and never goes ahead to look for another one, ***This is the reason one should understand that IDs should be unique per element***.

change to class name instead:

```
<table>
  <c forEach var="item" items="${manyItems}">
    <tr>
       <td class="item1"> ${item.data1} </td>
       <td class="item2"> ${item.data2} </td>
       <td> <button class="deleteButton"/> </td>
    </tr>
  </c:forEach>
</table>
```

and jquery:

```
$(function() {
  $('.deleteButton').click(function() {
    var ele = $(this).parent();
    /* fetch the other <td> siblings of the .deleteButton */
    /* delete code goes here having an ajax query*/
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

First think that, `id` is known unique, if u need to have click event for two `button`, u can use `class` for selecting the `button`, so try to follow the standards, `id` is unique `selector` and `class` is multiple `selector`.